# how to display error validations without clearing the entered input

Tags: grails, groovy

My code for validating entered URL values will be as below :

```
try{
        urls.eachWithIndex { u, i ->
            String countryCode = u.key;
            String url = urls["${u.key}"]
            if(url != ""){
            Boolean valid = helperService.isURLValid(url)
                if(valid == false){
                   this.errors.reject("Incorrect URL is entered for "+countries.get(countryCode)+" - please ensure to use a correct URL for More Games.")
                   return [];
                   // assert false
                    // params.gamesUrls = url
                }
            }
        }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.warn("Incorrect URL is entered", ex)
                    return [];
        }
```

the entered values are cleared when the URL validation fails.

How to display the errors but not to clear the entered input(tried return [], but is of no use)

here is the gsp code...

```
<g:form action="wizard">
            <table>
                <g:each in="${countries}" status="i" var="country">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
                        <td><img border="0" src="/wizard/image/flags/${country.key}" alt="" /> <label for="gamesUrls.${country.key}">${country.value}</label></td>
                        <td><g:textField name="gamesUrls.${country.key}" style="width:350px" value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" onchange="\$(this).addClassName('changed');" maxlength="255"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Revert" onClick="revertTextValue('gamesUrls.${country.key}')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
            </table>
            <g:submitButton name="back" value="Back" /> <g:submitButton name="next" value="Confirm" />
```

Comment: Is this in grails?  What calls this code?  Haven't I seen this question before?

Comment: yes this is in grails and this code will be executed in the post process of the groovy command and would return errors back to grails

Comment: is this code in your controller? What is being submitted? Kinda hard to help you out with just this. But the return [] should be changed to render your model (or at least submitted values) so you can render them back when this redirects back to your input page. But we need a bit more info to help out, like your gsp (or a snippet of it)

Comment: I have included my gsp as well(edited the question), the first snippet was controller code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this by keeping a check in gsp

```
<g:if test="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key) == null || 'User Cannot Edit this URL'.equals(moreGamesUrls?.get(country.key))}">
                            <td><g:textField name="gamesUrls.${country.key}" style="width:350px" data-default-value="" value="" onchange="\$(this).addClassName('changed');" maxlength="255"/></td>
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <td><g:textField name="gamesUrls.${country.key}" style="width: 350px;" data-default-value="${moreGamesUrls?.get(country?.key)}" value="${moreGamesUrls?.get(country?.key)}" onchange="\$(this).addClassName('changed');" maxlength="255"/></td>
                        </g:else>
```